# Spectral sequence from a stratification by closed subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I am looking for a reference for the following result: If $X$ is an algebraic variety and
$$X = T_n \supset T_{n-1} \supset \cdots \supset T_{-1} = \varnothing$$
is a stratification (edit: filtration) by closed subvarieties, then there is a spectral sequence
$$E^{p,q}_1 = H^{p+q}_c(T_p \setminus T_{p-1}) \implies H^{p+q}_c(X).$$
Looking for a reference I have found Dan Petersen using it several times here in MathOverflow, such as [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128965/thom-gysin-sequences-and-stratifications/128978#128978), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142426/f-curves-and-divisors-on-overline-mathcalm-g-n/142433#142433) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233067/a-spectral-sequence-for-computing-cohomology-of-a-space-from-that-of-its-strata/233103#233103). So what is the specific result and where can I find a proof of it?

Comment: I don't know a reference (in fact had not heard of this before), but I assume what you do is take the filtration of sheaves $0 = \mathbf Z_{U_n} \subseteq \cdots \subseteq \mathbf Z_{U_{-1}} = \mathbf Z_X$ and take the spectral sequence associated with this filtration [Tag [0BKK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BKK)] (where $U_i = X \setminus T_i$). (I'm a little unhappy about this because I want to use sheaf cohomology with compact support, not usual sheaf cohomology.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn The filtration still makes sense after extending by zero to a compactification, so applying the definition of compactly supported cohomology there is no problem.

Comment: What I had in mind is to take an argument like the one Hatcher uses at the beggining of _Spectral Sequences in Algebraic Geometry_, but relating the relative cohomology of $(X_p, X_{p-1})$ with the compactly supported cohomology of $X_p \setminus X_{p-1}$. The problem is that I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Could you quote here the argument you want to modify, to make it easier for someone trying to answer? It should definitely be possible - compactly supported cohomology is usually easier to think about and work with for these purposes.

Comment: If you just want a reference, you can look at  p 575 of my paper "The Leray spectral sequence is motivic", and then specialize, but in terms of understanding, it's probably simpler to work it for yourself along the lines of Will Sawin's first comment. PS I'm pretty sure Hatcher's title is *Spect. Seq. in  Algebraic Topology*, not that it matters.

Comment: I guess this question is for me. It would be easier to answer if you could say what you're unhappy about with the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233067/ . That answer contains both the argument in Remy's comment and a citation to Donu's paper...

Comment: @DanPetersen I guess that my problem is that I have never read about the functorial point of view for compactly supported cohomology. I suppose that there is some result relating the classical singular cohomology with compact supports $H^n_c(X)$ with $Rj_!(\mathbf{Z}), j: X \to *$, right? Do you have any recommendation about where I could read about this?

Comment: Try Dimca, Sheaves in Topology, Section 2.3 and thereabouts.